# Special journals for young scientists or regular peer reviewed papers

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I am a 16 year old researcher and was wondering whether to apply to publish my paper in a special journals for young scientists, which have a higher chance of acceptance, or to apply in a regular peer-reviewed journal which might have a less chance of acceptance. I am confused between the quality and impact factor of the two journals and don't know which will be better. My research is completely original and not to show off but kind-of revolutionary.

Comment: If your research is revolutionary, why submit to a lesser journal? Send it to Nature or Science or some other appropriate big journal with a wide audience.

Comment: Why settle for less, if you can get more? Good luck! Take care, however, if the lingo and similar factors also add up. There are normally senior co-authors for this, but I understand you as you are writing the article alone. You might also want to use `arXiv` to secure a time-stamp on your research.

Comment: @Allure yes I plan on sending to one of those journals you have mentioned. Can not tell which.

Comment: @OlegLobachev I have consulted with 3 researchers, all at high posts in research institutes, but none have seen the actual initial submission. Please do tell me about arXiv, like does it cost money, like Elsevier, and does it take interdisciplinary and applicative rather than theoretical papers. Thanks fo the help.

Comment: Err... arXiv is free, you can find the category that suits you and upload virtually anything there. https://arxiv.org

Comment: @OlegLobachev is it effective. Can I send my paper to a journal and upload it on arXiv as well